# Responsive menu and media query (CSS)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, css-position, media-queries

I am trying to make responsive menu bar and for that i am using media
 queries. So i am using this css code and using `position:absolute`
 property so my header don't expand with drop down menu
`position:absolute` property automatically applies on other media query
 so how i can prevent it ??

```
nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    #header-wrap {
        width:95%;
        background-color:#fff;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height:100px;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    }

    nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }

    nav li:hover ul {
        display:block;
    }

    nav li ul {
        width:100%;
    }

    nav li ul li {
        display:none;
        padding-left:10px;
        width:100%;
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your definition you set the position:absolute global

```
nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

There are now two ways. Only define position:absolute in the media query you need it or revert it in your media query where it should be normal. In your case also:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
nav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position: static;
}
```